# Returning grid results for grid solitaire puzzle

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was given the task of making a grid peg solitaire puzzle. Here are the programs, the basic puzzle file, and the actual grid solitaire puzzle:

**The puzzle software**

```
class Puzzle:
    """"
    Snapshot of a full-information puzzle, which may be solved, unsolved,
    or even unsolvable.
    """

    def fail_fast(self):
        """
        Return True iff Puzzle self can never be extended to a solution.

        Override this in a subclass where you can determine early that
        this Puzzle can't be solved.

        @type self: Puzzle
        @rtype: bool
        """
        return False

    def is_solved(self):
        """
        Return True iff Puzzle self is solved.

        This is an abstract method that must be implemented
        in a subclass.

        @type self: Puzzle
        @rtype: bool
        """
        raise NotImplementedError

    def extensions(self):
        """
        Return list of legal extensions of Puzzle self.

        This is an abstract method that must be implemented
        in a subclass.

        @type self: Puzzle
        @rtype: list[Puzzle]
        """
        raise NotImplementedError
```

**The grid peg solitaire puzzle with the above puzzle imported above.**:

```
from puzzle import Puzzle


class GridPegSolitairePuzzle(Puzzle):
    """
    Snapshot of peg solitaire on a rectangular grid. May be solved,
    unsolved, or even unsolvable.
    """

    def __init__(self, marker, marker_set):
        """
        Create a new GridPegSolitairePuzzle self with
        marker indicating pegs, spaces, and unused
        and marker_set indicating allowed markers.

        @type marker: list[list[str]]
        @type marker_set: set[str]
                          "#" for unused, "*" for peg, "." for empty
        """
        assert isinstance(marker, list)
        assert len(marker) > 0
        assert all([len(x) == len(marker[0]) for x in marker[1:]])
        assert all([all(x in marker_set for x in row) for row in marker])
        assert all([x == "*" or x == "." or x == "#" for x in marker_set])
        self._marker, self._marker_set = marker, marker_set

     # TODO
    # implement __eq__, __str__ methods
    # __repr__ is up to you
    #Received help from TA Bryan
    def __eq__(self, other):
        """
        Return whether GridPegSolitairePuzzle self is equivalent to other.
        @type self: GridPegSolitairePuzzle
        @type other: GridPegSolitairePuzzle | Any
        @rtype: bool
        >>> grid = [["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]]
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", ".", "*", "*"])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
        >>> gpsp1 = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})
        >>> grid = [["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]]
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", ".", "*", "*"])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
        >>> gpsp2 = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})
        >>> grid = [[".", ".", ".", ".", "."]]
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", ".", "*", "*"])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
        >>> gpsp3 = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})
        >>> gpsp1.__eq__(gpsp2)
        True
        >>> gpsp1.__eq__(gpsp3)
        False
        """
        #TA Bryan added return (type(other) == type(self) part for me
        return (type(other) == type(self) and
                self._marker == other._marker and
                self._marker_set == other._marker_set)

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Return a human-readable string representation of GridPegSolitairePuzzle.
        @type self: GridPegSolitairePuzzle
        @rtype: str
        >>> grid = [["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]]
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", ".", "*", "*"])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
        >>> gpsp1 = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})
        >>> print(gpsp1)
        * * * * *
        * * * * *
        * * * * *
        * * . * *
        * * * * *
        """
        return "\n".join([" ".join(row) for row in self._marker])

    def extensions(self):
        """
        Return list of extensions of GridPegSolitairePuzzle self.
        @type self: GridPegSolitairePuzzle
        @rtype: list[GridPegSolitairePuzzle]
        >>> grid = [[".", ".", ".", "*", "*"]]
        >>> grid.append([".", ".", ".", ".", "."])
        >>> grid.append([".", ".", ".", ".", "."])
        >>> grid.append([".", ".", ".", ".", "."])
        >>> grid.append([".", ".", ".", ".", "."])
        >>> gpsp1 = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})
        >>> L1 = gpsp1.extensions()
        >>> grid[0] = [".", ".", "*", ".", "."]
        >>> L2 = [GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})]
        >>> len(L1) == len(L2)
        True
        >>> all([s in L2 for s in L1])
        True
        >>> all([s in L1 for s in L2])
        True
        """
        legal = []

        # For each peg, checks whether it can be jumped up, down, left, or right
        # If so, that configuration is added to the list of legal extensions
        for r in range(len(self._marker)):
            for c in range(len(self._marker[r])):
                if self._marker[r][c] == "*":
                    legal.extend(jump_left(self._marker, r, c))
                    legal.extend(jump_right(self._marker, r, c))
                    legal.extend(jump_up(self._marker, r, c))
                    legal.extend(jump_down(self._marker, r, c))

        return legal

    def is_solved(self):
        """
        Returns true iff there is one peg, '*', remaining in the grid
        @type self: GridPegSolitairePuzzle
        @rtype: bool
        >>> grid = [[".", "*", ".", ".", "*"]]
        >>> grid.append([".", ".", "*", ".", "."])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", ".", "*", "*"])
        >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
        >>> gpsp1 = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})
        >>> grid = [[".", ".", ".", ".", "."]]
        >>> grid.append([".", ".", ".", ".", "."])
        >>> grid.append([".", ".", ".", ".", "."])
        >>> grid.append([".", ".", "*", ".", "."])
        >>> grid.append([".", ".", ".", ".", "."])
        >>> gpsp2 = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})
        >>> gpsp1.is_solved()
        False
        >>> gpsp2.is_solved()
        True
        """
        # Makes a list of how many pegs are in each row
        # Checks that one row has one peg, and the rest have none
        pegs = [row.count('*') for row in self._marker]
        return pegs.count(1) == 1 and pegs.count(0) == len(pegs) - 1


def jump_left(markers, row, column):
    """
    Returns the grid that results after the marker at (row, column) jumps left
    @type markers: list[list[str]]
    @type row: int
    @type column: int
    @rtype: list[GridPegSolitairePuzzle]
    >>> grid = [["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]]
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", ".", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> gpsp1 = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})
    >>> L1 = jump_left(gpsp1._marker, 3, 4)
    >>> grid[3][2] = "*"
    >>> grid[3][3] = "."
    >>> grid[3][4] = "."
    >>> L2 = [GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})]
    >>> L1 == L2
    True
    """
    # Checking bounds and whether the right pieces are in the positions needed
    if (column - 2) >= 0 and (markers[row][column - 2] == ".") and\
                             (markers[row][column - 1] == "*"):

        # Each row must be copied individually (since they are all lists)
        m_copy = []
        for i in range(len(markers)):
            m_copy.append(markers[i].copy())

        new_grid = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(m_copy, {"*", ".", "#"})

        # Performs the jump
        new_grid._marker[row][column] = "."
        new_grid._marker[row][column - 1] = "."
        new_grid._marker[row][column - 2] = "*"

        return [new_grid]

    else:
        return []


def jump_right(markers, row, column):
    """
    Returns the grid that results after the marker at (row, column) jumps right
    @type markers: list[list[str]]
    @type row: int
    @type column: int
    @rtype: list[GridPegSolitairePuzzle]
    >>> grid = [["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]]
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", ".", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> gpsp1 = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})
    >>> L1 = jump_right(gpsp1._marker, 3, 0)
    >>> grid[3][2] = "*"
    >>> grid[3][0] = "."
    >>> grid[3][1] = "."
    >>> L2 = [GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})]
    >>> L1 == L2
    True
    """
    # Checking bounds and whether the right pieces are in the positions needed
    if (column + 2) < len(markers[row]) and\
       (markers[row][column + 2] == ".") and\
       (markers[row][column + 1] == "*"):

        # Each row must be copied individually (since they are all lists)
        m_copy = []
        for i in range(len(markers)):
            m_copy.append(markers[i].copy())

        new_grid = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(m_copy,
                                          {"*", ".", "#"})

        # Performs the jump
        new_grid._marker[row][column] = "."
        new_grid._marker[row][column + 1] = "."
        new_grid._marker[row][column + 2] = "*"

        return [new_grid]

    else:
        return []


def jump_up(markers, row, column):
    """
    Returns the grid that results after the marker at (row, column) jumps up
    @type markers: list[list[str]]
    @type row: int
    @type column: int
    @rtype: list[GridPegSolitairePuzzle]
    >>> grid = [["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]]
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", ".", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> gpsp1 = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})
    >>> L1 = jump_up(gpsp1._marker, 4, 2)
    >>> grid[2][2] = "*"
    >>> grid[3][2] = "."
    >>> grid[4][2] = "."
    >>> L2 = [GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})]
    >>> L1 == L2
    True
    """
    # Checking bounds and whether the right pieces are in the positions needed
    if (row - 2) >= 0 and (markers[row - 2][column] == ".") and\
                          (markers[row - 1][column] == "*"):

        # Each row must be copied individually (since they are all lists)
        m_copy = []
        for i in range(len(markers)):
            m_copy.append(markers[i].copy())

        new_grid = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(m_copy,
                                          {"*", ".", "#"})

        # Performs the jump
        new_grid._marker[row][column] = "."
        new_grid._marker[row - 1][column] = "."
        new_grid._marker[row - 2][column] = "*"

        return [new_grid]

    else:
        return []


def jump_down(markers, row, column):
    """
    Returns the grid that results after the marker at (row, column) jumps down
    @type markers: list[list[str]]
    @type row: int
    @type column: int
    @rtype: list[GridPegSolitairePuzzle]
    >>> grid = [["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]]
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", ".", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> gpsp1 = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})
    >>> L1 = jump_down(gpsp1._marker, 1, 2)
    >>> grid[3][2] = "*"
    >>> grid[2][2] = "."
    >>> grid[1][2] = "."
    >>> L2 = [GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})]
    >>> L1 == L2
    True
    """
    # Checking bounds and whether the right pieces are in the positions needed
    if (row + 2) < len(markers) and\
            (markers[row + 2][column] == ".") and\
            (markers[row + 1][column] == "*"):

        # Each row must be copied individually (since they are all lists)
        m_copy = []
        for i in range(len(markers)):
            m_copy.append(markers[i].copy())

        new_grid = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(m_copy,
                                          {"*", ".", "#"})

        # Performs the jump
        new_grid._marker[row][column] = "."
        new_grid._marker[row + 1][column] = "."
        new_grid._marker[row + 2][column] = "*"

        return [new_grid]

    else:
        return []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest

    doctest.testmod()
    from puzzle_tools import depth_first_solve

    grid = [["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"],
            ["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"],
            ["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"],
            ["*", "*", ".", "*", "*"],
            ["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]]
    gpsp = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})
    import time

    start = time.time()
    solution = depth_first_solve(gpsp)
    end = time.time()
    print("Solved 5x5 peg solitaire in {} seconds.".format(end - start))
    print("Using depth-first: \n{}".format(solution))
```

The code works entirely, but the professor does not like how I broke up the function definitions into `jump_right`, `jump_left`, `jump_up`, `jump_down`. He says I should do this all in one function called `jump`. What would the code be for this?

Comment: The code works entirely?  The doctests fail for me.  I can come up with a solution that combines them, but it has the same doctest failure that yours gets.

Comment: @zondo can i see your solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to be noticed is that the code *is* just about identical.  When `row` and `column` are used, it is always either `+ 2`, `- 2`, `+ 1`, or `- 1`.  What I have done below is create a dictionary for the different directions.  Whenever you use `row + 1` in one function, it should instead be `row + rowadd` because in other functions, it might be `row`, `row + 1`, or `row - 1`.  Whenever you use `row + 2` in one function, int should be `row + (2 * rowadd)` because in other functions, it might be `row`, `row + 2`, or `row - 2`.  I have used constants at the beginning of the file to define what the directions are.  That way I am not hard-coding values.  Anyway, the code is here:

```
LEFT = "left"
RIGHT = "right"
UP = "up"
DOWN = "down"

def jump(markers, row, column, direction):
    """
    Returns the grid that results after the marker at (row, column) jumps in the direction of DIRECTION.
    @type markers: list[list[str]]
    @type row: int
    @type column: int
    @rtype: list[GridPegSolitairePuzzle]
    >>> grid = [["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]]
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", ".", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> gpsp1 = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})
    >>> L1 = jump(gpsp1._marker, 3, 0, RIGHT)
    >>> grid[3][2] = "*"
    >>> grid[3][0] = "."
    >>> grid[3][1] = "."
    >>> L2 = [GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})]
    >>> L1 == L2
    True
    """
   # Checking bounds and whether the right pieces are in the positions needed
    moves = {LEFT: (0, -1), RIGHT: (0, 1), UP: (-1, 0), DOWN: (1, 0)}
    rowadd, columnadd = moves[direction]
    if (column + (2*columnadd)) < len(markers[row + (2*rowadd)]) and\
       (markers[row + (2*rowadd)][column + (2*columnadd)] == ".") and\
       (markers[row + (2*rowadd)][column + columnadd] == "*"):

        # Each row must be copied individually (since they are all lists)
        m_copy = []
        for i in range(len(markers)):
            m_copy.append(markers[i].copy())

        new_grid = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(m_copy,
                                          {"*", ".", "#"})

        # Performs the jump
        new_grid._marker[row][column] = "."
        new_grid._marker[row + rowadd][column + columnadd] = "."
        new_grid._marker[row + (2*rowadd)][column + (2*columnadd)] = "*"

        return [new_grid]
   else:
        return []
```

I can't say absolutely that this works because I don't have the `puzzle_tools` module.  I do know that the doc tests don't work, but they fail with the exact same messages as how your current program fails.

Comment: can you show me how would i adjust def extensions, and thank you so much for the example

Comment: The doc string gives that.  Any time you would do `jump_right(...)`, change it to `jump(..., RIGHT)`.  Any time you would do `jump_left(...)`, change it to `jump(..., LEFT)`; etc.

Comment: so for something like legal.extend(jump_left(self._marker, r, c)), i should write legal.extend(jump(self._marker, r, RIGHT))

Comment: No.  It would be `legal.extend(jump(self._marker, r, c, LEFT))`.  You use the same arguments, but just add the direction to the end.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help, I appreciate it

Comment: It's my pleasure.  Anything to make me feel like I know something ;)